# getting indices when comparing multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have two numpy arrays, one an `RGB` image, one a lookup table of pixel values, for example:

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 9 , (3, 3, 3))
lut = np.random.randint(0, 9, (1,3,3))
```

What I'd like is to know the `x,y` coordinate in `lut` of pixels whose values are common to `img` and `lut`, so I tried:

```
for x in xrange(img.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(img.shape[1]):
            print np.transpose(np.concatenate(np.where(lut == img[x,y])))
```

At this point, the problem is that `img[x,y]`, which will be in the form of `[int_r, int_g, int_b]` does not get evaluated as a single element, so the three components get sought for separately in `img`...

I would like the output to be something like:

```
(x_coord, y_coord)
```

But I only get output in the form of:

```
[0 0 0]
[0 2 1]
[0 0 2]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 2]
[0 0 1]
[0 2 2]
[0 1 2]
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 9 , (3, 3, 3))
lut2 = img[1,2,:] # so that we know exactly the answer

# compare two matrices
img == lut2

array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)

# rows with all true are the matching ones
np.where( (img == lut2).sum(axis=2) == 3 )

(array([1]), array([2]))
```

I don't really know why lut is filled with random numbers. But, I assume that you want to look for the pixels that have the exactly same color. If so, this seems to work. Is this what you need to do?

Comment: yes, that is precisely what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: Grad that it helped. With Numpy, try to avoid loop. Enjoy numpy!

Answer (score 0):

@otterb 's answer works if `lut` is defined as a single [r,g,b] pixel slice, but it needs to be tweaked a little if you want to generalize this process to a multi-pixel `lut`:

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 9 , (3, 3, 3))
lut2 = img[0:1,0:2,:]

for x in xrange(lut2.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(lut2.shape[1]):
        print lut2[x,y]
        print np.concatenate(np.where( (img == lut2[x,y]).sum(axis=2) == 3 ))
```

yields:

```
[1 1 7]
[0 0]
[8 7 4]
[0 1]
```

where triplets are pixel values, and doublets are their coordinates in the `lut`.

Cheers, and thanks to @otterb!

PS: iteration over numpy arrays is bad. The above is not production code.

Comment: You might be interested in color maps available in matplotlib. For example, _matplotlib.cm.jet(range(255))_ will give you RGBA format look up table for JET color map. More colormaps here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html