# fastest way to get lookup table indices with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, lookup

This question follows [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107116/getting-indices-when-comparing-multidimensional-arrays/25108107#25108107), and **aims at accelerating the following code.** I built (with help) some code that takes pixel values from a **m x n x 3** `numpy.ndarray` (an RGB image), compares the pixel values with those of a (positional) lookup table, and outputs the pixel values **indices** of the lookup table, as follows:

```
img = np.random.randint(0, 9 , (3, 3, 3))
lut2 = img[0,0:2,:]

output = []
for x in xrange(lut2.shape[0]):
    if lut2[x] in img:
            output.append(np.concatenate(np.where( (img == lut2[x]).sum(axis=2) == 3 )))

print np.array(output)
```

### output :

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]]
```

**bug:** will not output correctly if you get `lut[x]` in more than one place in `img`. Maybe a better strategy would be to format the output as a nested list, since anything indexable would do. For example:

```
[[x_px1, y_px1], [[x_px2a, y_px2a], [x_px2b, y_px2b]]]
```

where `px2a` and `px2b` are separate pixels in `img` that have the same color value.

I have been fiddling with `numpy` indexation, but I can achieve nothing better. While the above works partially, it is of course very slow due to iteration on the array. If I feed it a common-sized image, it will take an unacceptable time to complete.

Could someone please point me towards a **faster solution?**

---

### Edit: summary of the ideal future algorithm I am aiming at:

```
  an image               all pixels replaced          all indices are
  (here, single ----->   by index in lut     ----->   reused in digital_scale
  black pixel)           (here, first pixel)          to output an array of scalars

  [[[0, 0, 0]]]          [[[0, 0]]]                   [[0]]

  array shape:           array shape:                 array shape:

  m X n X 3              m X n X 2                    m X n
```

The last `m X n` array would be used for 2 things:

- plot the data on a different time interval, by storing the arrays in a database.
- do a statistical analysis of the changes in the array due to some external events

**note:** the base images are already a kind of plot, but I have no access to the numerical data, so I need to reverse the plots.

---

### Some (optional) requested precisions on the aim of my code:

A lookup table usually is based on pixel values, not position. In this case though, position would be better (I think). The `lut` array in the above code is a dummy for a linear color scale representing velocity that I need to digitize, as found below:

[image: linear color scale]

Since each level of the scale is a uniform color, the scale can in fact be reduced to an array of dimensions `1 X height X 3` (for RGB, HSV, etc.). I can in fact drop the first dimension and iterate over an array of `height X 3`. Things I use to digitize the scale are:

- it is centered around zero
- it is symmetrical
- it is linear
- maximum and minimum values are known

Therefore, the digital representation of this scale will be:

```
digital_scale = np.linspace(-max_speed, max_speed, lut.shape[0])
```

I only need to get the `y` index of the pixel value I look for in `lut`, and then the `y`th element of `digital_scale` to output the value I need (a scalar, see algorithm summary above).

Comment: What is the actual output you want (i.e. surely you are after the data in some kind of array format, rather than printing it out)? What exactly are you trying to do? A LUT is normally a function of the image values, not the indices.

Comment: Do you need the final output as an ndarray, can it be something else?  If there is more than one pixel for an LUT *level*, how does that output look?  For testing purposes, you may want to use ```np.random.seed(1); img = np.random.randint(0, 9 , (3, 3, 3)); img[1, 0, :] = img[0,0,:]```.

Comment: @wwii Thank you for your interest. Output as an ndarray would be preferred, but I could make do with anything that I could index, such as a list. The reason for that is that I want to use the index to fetch the corresponding element of `digital_scale`, which would be my final result (see edits above) Yes, there could be more than 1 pixel for any LUT level (a thing at which my code fails, see **bug** above mentioned, and I would like the output to be a nested list or array for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kd-tree, here is a demo:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

H, W = 200, 100

np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (H, W, 3))
b = np.random.randint(0, 20, (20, 3))
tree = spatial.cKDTree(a.reshape(-1, 3))
res = tree.query_ball_point(b, 0.5, p=1)
print res
```

the output is:

```
[[] [577, 17471] [14636, 4515, 13693, 10988, 15013] [16935, 8576, 13286]
 [2443] [7743, 5914] [] [7469, 19736, 13395, 14992, 9083, 15514]
 [1167, 11416] [3903, 4968] [16504, 2996, 10805, 2264] [] [6725]
 [14437, 5888] [17667] [4681, 2545, 6442] [15067, 4533]
 [7876, 2235, 10152, 3288] [15404, 5691, 17216]
 [15586, 9916, 16938, 15931, 4828, 4069]]
```

to theck the result of index 2:

```
rows, cols = np.where(np.all(a == b[None, None, 2], axis=-1))
assert np.all(rows * W + cols == sorted(res[2]))
```

Comment: What this does seems extremely complex. I understand the result, but not the internals, even when reading the documentation. I will try it as soon as possible (still this week)! Thank you for your answer :-)